# Currency conversion :- Handling a scenario of absent exchange rate in a SQL table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables , for simplification consider these

**Revenue** :- Contains revenue in USD

| Timestamp | id | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 1 | 100 |
| Cell 2 | 2 | 200 |

**Xrate** :- Contains USD to EUR conversion rates

| Timestamp | xrate |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 0.9 |
| Cell 2 | 0.8 |

I join these two tables, apply some filters and grouping and get a result set as such

| Timestamp | id | revenue | xrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 1 | 100 | 0.9 |
| Cell 2 | 2 | 200 | 0.8 |

Now the xrate might not be available for a particular timestamp, in which case the join would yield NULL for that particular row.

I want to calculate converted revenue in EUR i.e. `revenue*xrate`, but ONLY WHEN there is absolutely no NULL value in xrate or exchange rates for all the timestamps for revenue table are available.

So I was thinking to have a separate column `adjusted_xrate` where if *ANY xrate is NULL/NA then EVERY row in adjusted_rate would be 1, else it would be same as xrate*, and then doing `revenue * adjusted_xrate`

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL query, snowflake to be specific.

I thought of using different Aggregate functions like MAX, COUNT, but couldn't see any of these approaches fitting my use case.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "absolutely no NULL value in xrate". Does this mean there will be a record for each Timestamp in Xrate but the xrate field could be NULL? Or does it mean there will not even be a record for Timestamp in Xrate?

Comment: `Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL query, snowflake to be specific.` By Snowflake do you mean snowflake.com the cloud DB, because it is not MySQL an anyway. And as an side I am interested how/why if you mean this, you think this, because this mistake is made quite a lot by new people, and I am trying to find the source of this misunderstanding.

Comment: My bad I meant SQL not MySQL , thanks for correcting

Comment: @June7 Sorry for the confusion , I meant that after the left join , If the matching timestamp is not present in table xrate , then the value for xrate would be NULL for the particular timestamp after the left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are meaning Snowflake the cloud DB (which has nothing to do with MySQL) then, [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if) can be used to count the NULLs:

So with a more expansive example data:

```
with revenue(id, timestamp,  revenue) as (
    select * from values
        (1, '2023-12-04 08:29:00.000'::timestamp, 100 ),
        (2, '2023-12-04 08:29:00.000'::timestamp, 200 ),
        (2, '2023-12-04 09:29:00.000'::timestamp, 201 ),
        (3, '2023-12-04 09:29:00.000'::timestamp, 300 ),
        (3, '2023-12-04 10:29:00.000'::timestamp, 301 ),
        (4, '2023-12-04 10:29:00.000'::timestamp, 400 )        
), xrate(timestamp, xrate) as (
    select * from values
        ('2023-12-04 08:29:00.000'::timestamp, 0.9 ),
        ('2023-12-04 09:29:00.000'::timestamp, 0.8 )
)
```

we can use MIN, MAX, COUNT_IF to show the first to skip nulls in non-nulls are present, like most [Aggregate function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-aggregation) do, but COUNT_IF can be used to count the event we care about, thus:

```
select 
    r.*
    ,x.xrate
    ,min(x.xrate) over (partition by r.id) as check_a
    ,max(x.xrate) over (partition by r.id) as check_b
    ,count_if(x.xrate is null) over (partition by r.id) as check_c
from revenue as r
left join xrate as x
    on r.timestamp = x.timestamp
order by 1,2;
```

[image]

Thus the final bit of logic using an [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff):

```
select 
    r.*
    ,x.xrate
    ,iff(count_if(x.xrate is null) over (partition by r.id) > 0, 1, x.xrate) as adj_xrate
    ,r.revenue * adj_xrate as math
from revenue as r
left join xrate as x
    on r.timestamp = x.timestamp
order by 1,2;
```

gives:

[image]

### After Comment:

Ah, yes swapping to use a `count_if(x.xrate is null) over()` for all rows, would work, but yes, two aggregate functions (over each other) is too much ambiguity for the optimizer, aka:

```
select 
    r.*
    ,x.xrate
    ,iff(count_if(x.xrate is null) over() > 0, 1, x.xrate) as adj_xrate
    ,r.revenue * adj_xrate as math
    ,sum(math) over () as sum_math
from revenue as r
left join xrate as x
    on r.timestamp = x.timestamp
order by 1,2;
```

gives:

> Window function [SUM(IFF(SYS_VW.XRATE_1 IS NULL, 1, 0)) OVER ()] may not be nested inside another window function.

so this needs to become a nest-select, or CTE:

```
select 
    n.*
    ,sum(math) over () as sum_math
from (
    select 
        r.*
        ,x.xrate
        ,iff(count_if(x.xrate is null) over() > 0, 1, x.xrate) as adj_xrate
        ,r.revenue * adj_xrate as math
    from revenue as r
    left join xrate as x
        on r.timestamp = x.timestamp
) as n
order by 1,2;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution @Simeon !

There's a problem here , that is If any XRATE is null , then every ADJ_XRATE should be 1. Basically the requirement is that if the exchange rates for any timestamp is not available , then we don't want currency conversion , which is why ADJ_XRATE should be 1 for all rows.


I was able to fix this by partitioning by nothing , using just over().


I ran into another problem after this , I want to get the sum of the converted revenue.
sum(revenue*adj_xrate) , but snowflake doesn't support window function inside an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

I can't test with snowflake since I don't have it, so I will offer a fairly generic syntax which should work with any SQL flavor.

A subquery with Count aggregation is one approach, like:

```
SELECT Revenue.Timestamp, id, revenue, xrate, 
    revenue*IFF((SELECT Count(*) FROM Revenue 
                WHERE Timestamp NOT IN(SELECT Timestamp FROM Xrate))=0,xrate,1) AS AdjRev
FROM Revenue LEFT JOIN Xrate ON Revenue.Timestamp=Xrate.Timestamp;
```